# Get value from stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have the following stored procedure in sql server and i am trying to take the permission value with C#.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPermission]
@userName varchar(50),
@permission int output
AS
BEGIN

select @permission = PERMISSION from USERS where UserName = @userName

END;
```

My C# code is the following:

```
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
            "sp_getPermission", conn);


        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


        cmd.Parameters.Add(
            new SqlParameter("@UserName", textBox1.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(
           new SqlParameter("@permission", "none"));




        SqlDataReader rdr = null;

        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        MessageBox.Show( rdr["Permission"].ToString() );
```

But i get the following error on the last line of C# code:

> Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's simply this:

first, remove the output parameter `@permission`, then, change your procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPermission]
@userName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

select PERMISSION from USERS where UserName = @userName

END;
```

and for read the permission, use the [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "sp_getPermission", conn);


cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


cmd.Parameters.Add(
    new SqlParameter("@UserName", textBox1.Text));

var permission = (System.Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ParameterDirection of the permission parameter on the SqlCommand to `ParameterDirection.Output`

Also, as you are not resulting a resultset, no need to use ExecuteReader. Just do:

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `Read` your `SqlDataReader`:

```
rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (rdr.HasRows()){
   rdr.Read()
   MessageBox.Show( rdr["Permission"].ToString() );
   rdr.Close()
}
```

---

However, I don't believe you need a SqlDataReader for this situation. The following should work:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(
           new SqlParameter("@permission", "none"));
cmd.Parameters["@permission"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show(cmd.Parameters["@permission"].Value);
```

Comment: I get an error on cmd.Parameters(@permission)..... error"Error 1 Non-invocable member 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.Parameters' cannot be used like a method"